# Form does nothing, send nothing php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

i'm kind of new in this and could use some help. You see, i have a form in a login page, but when i click the button it does nothing, not even an error message. It should send me to the page called "formulario.php". I just can't find the error and i have seen lots of tutorials and books.

This is my php file: login.php

```
<?php
#connect to mysql
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "admin") or die ("PROBLEMAS AL INTENTO ESTE DE CONEXION");

#connect to database
mysql_select_db("generatedata", $conexion) or die ("ERROR AL TRATAR DE CONECTAR CON DATABASE");

#form parameters
$nombre = $_REQUEST['username'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];    

#query to select users from the database
$estandar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '.$nombre.' and `contrasena` = '.$pass.'") or die(mysql_error());

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($estandar)){

    header("Location: formulario.php");
}else {
    echo "error";#header("Location: 404.html");
}   

?>
```

and my form

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
<table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" id="username"> </td>
      </tr>
        <td>contraseña:</td>
        <td><input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" value="" id="password"> </td>
      </tr>
</table>

    <button type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
    <button type="reset" name="res" value="res" class="btn btn-primary">LImpiar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: By "does nothing" do you mean it shows a blank page?  That's often an indication of an unreported error in PHP.  Check the PHP logs, turn on error reporting.  Also please note that there are two significant problems in the code.  1) The database code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  2) You're storing user passwords in plain text.  Both of these are very bad things.

Comment: `'.$nombre.'` and `'.$pass.'` remove the dots or add double quotes. `mysql_error()` should have told you there's an error, but you failed to show it to us.

Comment: Also sanitize your user inputs as you're open to SQL Injections. I'll also drop a note for you to look into PDO/MySQLi Prepared Statements since the `mysql_*` library is deprecated.

Comment: it doesn't show me a blank page, it just stay in the same page. And about the security things, well, i know about it's vulnerabilities but firs i just want to make it work. I wanted to post it as simple as possible

Comment: `#header("Location: 404.html")` remove the `#` and add `exit;` after each header, unless you want to redirect?

Comment: i forgot to delete the `#header("Location: 404.html")`  but yes, It should redirect it

Comment: Change it to `'".$nombre."'` and `'".$pass."'` see what that says. Also both `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`

Comment: Yet I don't know what you're trying to do with `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($estandar))` you're not doing anything with `$row`.

Comment: [Did you try this?................](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846325/form-does-nothing-send-nothing-php#comment45961360_28846325)

Comment: @Fred -ii- yeah, thanks for that, i actually don't know why is  that in there. anyway y changed to this `if (mysql_num_rows($estandar) == 1) `  and also changed it to `'".$nombre."'`  ... still, nothing happens

Comment: Check your column types and `if (mysql_num_rows($estandar) == 1)` to `if (mysql_num_rows($estandar) >0 )` sometimes that makes a difference. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: It will be nice to be user =' and password= or '1'='1

Comment: Everything works now!  thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly on my computer. Meaning your data is the issue. Try this and let us know the value of `$sql`

```
<?php
#connect to mysql
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "admin") or die ("PROBLEMAS AL INTENTO ESTE DE CONEXION");

#connect to database
mysql_select_db("generatedata", $conexion) or die ("ERROR AL TRATAR DE CONECTAR CON DATABASE");

#form parameters
$nombre = $_REQUEST['username'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];    

#query to select users from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '".$nombre."' and `contrasena` = '".$pass."'";

print $sql;

$estandar = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($estandar)){

    header("Location: formulario.php");
}else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: executing that prints   `SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '.fernando.' and `contrasena` = '.123456.'error`

Comment: Did you see what i fixed?

Comment: It was taking the dots as part of you username and your password. This should work. Now you can remove print $sql.

Comment: Wow! now it works!  finally i can get some sleep.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @FernandoMacias if you think this is the answer can you please mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Check **Select** Query Line...

```
$estandar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where
usuario = '".$nombre."' and `contrasena` = '".$pass."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Actually When you are checking for login purpose You have to use **mysql_num_rows** not an mysql_fetch_Array..